# Error when installing LESS through NPM on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, installation, less, failed-installation

When I try and install LESS via NPM on my Ubuntu 14.04 system I get this error:

```
peter@ubuntudevsvr:~$ sudo npm install -g less
[sudo] password for peter:
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/less
npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: less
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/peter/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-20-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "less"
npm ERR! cwd /home/peter
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: less
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/peter/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Does anyone have any clue as to how I can fix this? Any details or help will be greatly appreciated.

I've tried some of the solutions that are on here with a same-ish issue but to no avail.

Edit:
Here is the npm-debug.log:

```
info it worked if it ends with ok
verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', '-g', 'less' ]
info using npm@1.1.4
info using node@v0.6.12
verbose config file /home/peter/.npmrc
verbose config file /usr/etc/npmrc
verbose config file /usr/share/npm/npmrc
silly exec /usr/bin/node "/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-get-uid-gid.js" "nobody" 1000
silly spawning [ '/usr/bin/node',
silly spawning   [ '/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-get-uid-gid.js', 'nobody', 1000 ],
silly spawning   null ]
silly output from getuid/gid {"uid":65534,"gid":1000}
silly output from getuid/gid 
verbose cache add [ 'less', null ]
silly cache add: name, spec, args [ undefined, 'less', [ 'less', null ] ]
verbose parsed url { pathname: 'less', path: 'less', href: 'less' }
verbose addNamed [ 'less', '' ]
verbose addNamed [ null, '' ]
silly name, range, hasData [ 'less', '', false ]
verbose raw, before any munging less
verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './less' ]
verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/less
http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/less
ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: less
ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
ERR! You may report this log at:
ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
ERR! or use
ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/peter/npm-debug.log npm
ERR! 
ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-20-generic
ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "less"
ERR! cwd /home/peter
ERR! node -v v0.6.12
ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: less
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Can you copy-paste your npm-debug.log file relating to this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ubuntu+node+npm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer from [@therefromhere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8331/therefromhere) helped greatly, I shall post it here:

I had this issue with `npm v1.1.4` (and `node v0.6.12`), which are the `Ubuntu 12.04` repository versions.

It looks like that version of `npm` isn't supported any more, updating node (and npm with it) resolved the issue.

First, uninstall the outdated version (optional, but I think this fixed an issue I was having with global modules not being pathed in).

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
```

Then install from Chris Lea's repo:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

From: [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os)

Comment: You maybe want to note which npm and nodejs versions you finally installed.

Comment: Asof now it will give you v0.10.37